# Most Efficient way to detect duplicate http requests

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, servicestack

I'm using service stack to accept http requests that add rows to a back-end database, fairly standard stuff. The problem I have now is that sometimes, the devices sending data to the service, send the same request milliseconds apart. This then leads to database constraint errors as the first request was still inserting the new rows, etc etc

So, I'm thinking I need to find a way to detect a duplicate request and either ignore it or throw an HttpError back to the client. The idea I have at the moment is to store the full raw POST data to a temp table, and delete it once the processing is complete. On each POST request, I'd lookup the data in there and ignore if it's a duplicate. Is there any easier way to detect duplicate http requests in ServiceStack?

Comment: There is no such thing as a duplicate http request. Http is designed to accept multiple requests in parallel, often with the same parameters - you need to design your program to be able to deal with this situation.

Comment: To prevent it you could use a clickshield. Add an invisible <div> element (position absolute, transparent background) on your page once a request is sent, and remove it when an response is received.

Comment: @Code4R7 The data comes from an android device. The data to be uploaded is queued, and sent after some time. It's not via a web interface.

Comment: @theMayer Let me re-phrase then. The same POST data is sent multiple times, milliseconds apart. I do check if the data already exists in the database, however, since the same data is coming in 1ms later, the previous request is still processing and so it also checks and thinks the row isn't in the database and tries to save it again.

Comment: Maybe do one transaction at a time to the database. You might have a problem where the second request gets executed before the first.

Comment: @the_lotus Was thinking the same, wrapping the entire code in a TransactionScope, however the code does a lot. Saving data to the db, posts images to AWS, sends GCM messages, etc So this may not work, I'll try it though.

Comment: Maybe just the db part should be serial while the rest could be parallel. Depending on how the data is stored in the queue, you could already know if a request added to the queue is a duplicate of something already in the list.

Comment: What are you going to do if these two requests arrive at the exact same instant? Your software needs to be capable of dealing with that edge case gracefully. What you have is an architectural issue- but as we don't know the architecture, there is not much I can offer in the way of a solution.

Comment: And to add to the above, what I mean to illustrate is that you have a web server that accepts and processes more than one request at a time. From the server's perspective, it is blissfully unaware of any other requests being processed; thus, if you have a constrained resource or some other point of contention, it is up to your application architecture to come up with an *appropriate* means of preventing the resource contention. Since we don't know the parameters you have at your disposal to address the constraint, this question cannot be intelligently answered.

Comment: @theMayer I understand, it's a lot to explain as it has evolved slowly over time and is now one complicated method, doing way too much for a single function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A common way to prevent duplicate requests is for clients to send a unique code (aka noonce) like a Guid with the request and have the Server reject the request e.g. with `throw HttpError.Conflict("Duplicate Request")` if a request with the same code is sent.

If you have multiple app servers I'd recommend storing the unique codes in a Redis Set, otherwise for a single app server storing it in a static `ConcurrentDictionary<string,bool>` or `ConcurrentBag<string>` will work.